# Reemplazo de geometrias null con vacíos en R

Tags: r, geolocalización, geojson

Tengo esta **base de datos**:  (https://datos.gob.ar/dataset/energia-cantidad-usuarios-gas-natural-red-por-segmento-calle/archivo/energia_ae05ccf6-b486-44ea-89a1-1d315cdbd5bd)

Cuando lo levanto en `R` con los siguientes comandos:

```
gas <- st_read("cantidad-de-usuarios-de-gas-de-red-por-segmento-de-calle-shp.shp")
gas <- gas %>%
  st_transform(st_crs(amba_sin_caba))
```

Corre perfecto, pero tira la siguiente leyenda:

> "replacing null geometries with empty geometries Simple feature
>   collection with 1349554 features and 3 fields (with 637693 geometries
>   empty)"

Eso es un error del archivo que se sube o hay que levantarlo de otra forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facundo,

la pregunta obvia ¿el resultado que estás obteniendo es el que esperas o hay algún problema? Si es el que esperas no le prestes mucha atención, es solamente un mensaje, ni alcanza a ser un `Warning`.

Según este hilo https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1034 el desarrollador de `sf` no está de acuerdo con que esa librería tenga soporte para geometrías `NULL`. Por lo que entiendo entonces lo que hace es coercionar las geometrías `NULL` del driver de `GDAL` (que es el que hace la lectura) por un equivalente válido para los objetos de la clase `sf` (empty geometries).

Aparentemente no es nada grave, a menos que más abajo en el procesamiento estés usando alguna función que espere recibir geometría `NULL`. No sería el caso si usas la librería `sf` para todo el procesamiento del objeto cartográfico.

Comment: No en realidad debería haber más datos y no geometrías null, no sé si el problema es el shape o si tengo que usar otra librería para abrir ese archivo de manera correcta